# Given travel ban in South Africa although I did not overstay

Tags: overstaying, south-africa

I traveled to SA in December 2018 and was given a 3 month visa stamp. I spent a few days in SA, and then I entered Mozambique through land border and stayed there for a few days, before heading back to South Africa and departing from there. I spent a total of 2 weeks in both countries, and had no issues at all while exiting either one.
On my next trip to Mozambique in 2022, I had a long transit in South Africa and was asking if I could leave the airport on a visitor’s visa. I was then told by the passport control officer that I was had an entry ban for previously overstaying my visa! This never happened! I was never communicated that when I left South Africa the first time, I left with absolutely no problems, I had not overstayed, and have an exit stamp on my passport to prove it. What should I do as I am supposed to be going there in December (almost 5 years after my first visit) and I’m worried I won’t be allowed to enter. How do I even know if I am listed as “undesirable”. Should there not be an indication on my passport? I’ve tried to contact the embassy where I live and the Home Affairs in South Africa with absolutely no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did the Officer say when you showed your exit stamp? What other proof do you have that you did not overstay eg flight tickets? Were you given / did you ask for any paperwork setting out the ban? How long was it for?

Comment: That’s all the information I was provided with. She didn’t even ask to see my exit stamp; it was a transit years later and she said “your passport has a ban on it”. 
I was never provided any paperwork stating a ban when I left SA in 2019.

Comment: never had any issues, was never even told I overstayed (because I didn’t), and wasn’t even asked to pay a fine. All of my stamps are in my passport proving that I left SA and got into my home country wishing 2 weeks, when the visa I had was for 3 months. 
I have no other information on my supposed ban. No indication of how long or anything on my passport stating I have a ban. 
I really have no idea who to ask about this or what to do. The embassy isn’t responding and neither is Home Affairs in SA.

Comment: That's a tricky situation. Since none of the official channels are responding you may have to engage a South African immigration lawyer.